# How to use d3.legend.color() in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 v3 code like this :

```
var legendLinear = d3.legend.color()
    .shapeWidth(Math.round(svgW/8))
    .shapeHeight(containerW/8/3/2)
    .orient('horizontal')
    .scale(ordinal);

svg.call(legendLinear);
```

But in d3 v4 I get error d3.legend is undefined

What is the proper code for v4? I searched web but i get nothing.

Comment: You are using the old version of d3-legend. Susie Lu's page has the new version, which works with v4: http://d3-legend.susielu.com/ Pay attention to the fact that the methods' names have been *flattened*, according to the changes in v4: now, it is `d3.legendColor()`, not `d3.legend.color()`.